# Нужно ли закрывать поток?

Tags: java, многопоточность, поток-ввода

В общем один поток принимал данные от клиента, а что произойдет с этим потоком если я закрою сокет?

```
public void run() {
    String message;
    try {
        while((message = reader.readLine()) !=null) { 
            tell(message)
        }
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.PrintStackTrace
    };
}
```

Comment: поток перестанет принимать данные

Answer (score 0, accepted):

поток прекратит свою работу, так как читать больше неоткуда, и потоки надо закрывать

```
public void run(){
  String message;
  try (reader){
    while((message = reader.readLine()) !=null){ 
      tell(message)
    }
  }
  catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();};
}
```

Comment: Получается что он сам закроется? Разве не нужен interupt?

Comment: Сам закроется, `IOException` ловите если нужно удержать поток.

Comment: Извините, а не могли вы мне объяснить как поток понимает, что он должен что-то принять? Почему он просто не может пройти до конца метода run()?

Comment: Поток ничего не понимает, что-то должен принять непонятно по вашему коду, ну я ужу объяснил в предыдущем коменте что кидает исключение.